# Why does tt in declarative macros not expect the token "::"?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I have written the following macro:

```rs
macro_rules! foo {
    ($bar:tt) => {
       fn baz() {
           $tt
       }
    }
}
```

I am using it like this:

```rs
foo! {
    String::new();
}
```

This produces the following error: error: no rules expected the token `::` label: no rules expected this token in the macro call

I find this very confusing since I was under the impression that tt can match any regular code token.

Comment: According to the reference, `tt` matches "a single token or tokens in matching delimiters `()`, `[]`, or `{}`". `String::new()` would be an `expr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tt` matches a *single* token tree, i.e. only the `String`. If you want to match any *sequence* of tokens, use repeated `tt`:

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    ($($bar:tt)*) => {
       fn baz() {
           $($bar)*
       }
    }
}
```